# Ratio test for radius of convergence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

Consider the power series $\sum c_nz^n$. Here is a theorem-definition from baby Rudin:
[image]

Now, Theorem 3.37 implies that $Q:=\frac{1}{\lim \sup |c_{n+1}/c_n|}\le R$. So if $Q$ is infinite, then it is equal to $R$. But if $Q$ is finite, it need not be equal to $R$. Thus, in general, $Q\ne R$.

However, I don't understand why one can't mimic the proof of 3.39 to prove actually that $Q=R$ always. Namely,

$$\lim \sup |\frac{c_{n+1}z^{n+1}}{c_nz^n}|=|z|\lim\sup |\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}|,$$

and if the latter is $< 1$, then the series converges (in that case $|z|<Q)$; if the latter is $> 1$, then the series diverges (and $|z|> Q$ in that case).

So it seems we can define the radius of convergence as $Q$. But, as noted above, this is not true. Where is a mistake in my reasoning?

Comment: If the limit exists, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{c_n}{c_{n+1}}\right|$$is also the radius of convergence (as via the ratio test). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence

Comment: *Hadamard's formula* is stronger than the ratio test, because the limit superiot of $\sqrt{|c_n|}$ always exist, whereas the ratio $\dfrac{|c_n|}{|c_{n+1}|}$ is not necessarily defined for all $n$ large enough (think of lacunary series).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not true that if $|z|\limsup|c_{n+1}/c_n|>1$ then the series diverges.

In fact there are big problems here if $c_n=0$ for some $n$. But that's not the only problem. Consider the sequence

$$(c_n)=(1,2,1/4,2/4,1/9,2/9\dots),$$

or $c_{2k}=1/(k+1)^2$, $c_{2k+1}=2/(k+1)^2$. Let $z=1$. Then $|z|\limsup|c_{n+1}/c_n|=2$, but $\sum c_nz^n$ converges.